# Apple Developer Program minimum requirements to generate new Provisioning Profiles for existing app

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

We previously developed apps with dev accounts enrolled in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program. We recently made the call to cease developing in iOS but still have roughly 50 devices active, running around 15 apps that we are continuing to support to the extent of reissuing Provisioning Profiles each year.

The process for the last 12 months has been generating new Provisioning Profiles once logged into **developer.apple.com** and generating a new .ipa file with iResign (https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign).

Our Apple Developer Enterprise Program is up for renewal and I'm wondering, **is it necessary to renew the full membership in order to simply generate new Provisioning Profiles?**

Would I be able to use Ad Hoc profiles?

The apps have been reissued to devices by a server accessed through Safari on the device. We do not have the UDID for the devices but may be able to get them if necessary for Ad Hoc profiles (the devices are scattered across the country).

Answer (score 0):

> is it necessary to renew the full membership in order to simply generate new Provisioning Profiles?

**Yes.**

After a lot of back and forth with Apple, this was the definitive answer we came to. This is unfortunate given it is only to support legacy applications that are no longer receiving any updates other than Provisioning Profiles.

Hopefully this can serve as a notice to any small-time devs looking to build in iOS to consider ongoing costs.